# Iphone App Rejected by apple App Store for 1.0 Binary Rejected

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

They are saying This app duplicates the content and functionality of other apps submitted by your but this is my first app to be submitted and I never submitted apps before.

From Apple:

> 4. 3 Design: Spam
>    Guideline 4.3 - Design
>
> This app duplicates the content and functionality of other apps submitted by you or another developer to the App Store, which is considered a form of spam.
>
> Apps that simply duplicate content or functionality create clutter, diminish the overall experience for the end user, and reduce the ability of developers to market their apps.
>
> The next submission of this app may require a longer review time, and this app will not be eligible for an expedited review until this issue is resolved.
>
> Next Steps
>
> - Review the Design section of the App Store Review Guidelines.
> - Ensure your app is compliant with all sections of the App Store Review Guidelines and the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer Program.
> - Once your app is fully compliant, resubmit your app for review.
>
> Submitting apps designed to mislead or harm customers or evade the review process may result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account. Review the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer Program to learn more about our policies regarding termination"

What should I do?

Comment: "*or another developer*" - Perhaps your app is too much like existing app(s).  You may need to come up with a different app concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I send my company Indian government registration documents like trademark certificate and other to apple team & in that mail i also written that this app content is not copied from any other apps.
So they accept my application 
And release app to apple App Store.

Answer (score 0):

They don't mean that you have copied your own app.

They mean that your application is a very close replica in functionality or data or design to an existing application in the app store. Think of it as if I decided to upload a clone of WhatsApp to the app store. It would be misleading and create duplicates in the app store.

Apple take a strict stance on this and unless you add major changes in functionality and visuals to distinguish your app so that it stands as its own product it will not be allowed onto the App Store.